# Cambiar el formato de hora a 24 en HTML

Tags: html

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formato del `input type="time"` a 24 horas?

Busqué las etiquetas de HTML5 pero no hay ninguna respecto a la que necesito.

Comment: Por favor, **[edit] tu pregunta** agregando lo que hayas intentado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tan facil como esto ( ⚠ si es que tienes el ordenador en formato `24h` y usas Chrome):

```html
<input type="time"/>
```

<sub>Nota: Es muy nuevo y no está soportado aun en Firefox o versiones de Internet Explorer y Edge</sub>

O puedes usar librerias externas como TimePicker.js:

```js
var timepicker = new TimePicker('time', {
  lang: 'en',
  theme: 'blue-grey'
});
timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
  
  var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
  evt.element.value = value;

});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="time" placeholder="Horas:Minutos">
</div>
```

Tienes eventos como:

```
timepicker.on('open', function(evt){

});

timepicker.on('close', function(evt){

});
```

Comment: lois6b, disculpa, me refiero al atributo. En w3schools dice que si es un atributo nuevo en HTML5.

Comment: Ahh. si, es nuevo. Se pueden usar librerias externas. Esto si te funciona, simplifica mucho las cosas hahah

Comment: Gracias el script funciona muy bien al parecer se necesita de javascript o jQuery, pense que solo se necesitaba html

Comment: @JoseLuisGP si ya que el propio de HTML5 que puse primero es muy nuevo, no funciona en todos y el formato para cada navegador varia. De momento, script. este al menos no usa jQuery, pero con él hay muchas mas opciones de timepicker